# Can "dip X in Y" mean just "put X in Y" without taking X out of Y?

Tags: word-meaning

I can't understand
whether "dipping X in Y" necessarily involves "taking X out of Y"
or it can mean only "putting X in Y without taking X back".

For example ([academic.ru](https://top_english.academic.ru/23511/dip)):
**(1)** *She dipped the blouse into the hot suds*.

Does (1) mean (1a) or (1b)?:
**(1a)** *She put the blouse into the hot suds*.
**(1b)** *She put the blouse into the hot suds and took it out*.

Comment: When I hear that, I think she put the blouse into the hot suds, and that's all. Next, I'm expecting to hear what she did with the blouse in the suds, like maybe scrub it under the surface. However, most dictionary definitions of "dip" that involve putting something in something say "quickly in and out".

Comment: I think dip means put in and take out. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dip . In the other sense, dip means drop and not come back up again. "Share prices dipped this week".